How many strings made of $a$ "A"s and $b$ "B"s are there such that at any point in writing it there are never $k$ more "A"s than "B"s?
I was dealing with a problem stating: "What is the probability that, picking one ball at a time from a jar containing 1,016 red balls and 1,008 green balls, there is never a moment where the number of red and green balls left in the jar is the same?".
I tried to translate it into combinatorial strings, made of 1,016 "A"s and 1,008 "B"s, representing respectively red balls and green balls taken from the jar. The problem is then: how many strings made this way are such that there are never $n+8$ "A"s and $n$ "B"s in it, for every substring going from character 1 to i, $1\le i\le 2023$? Saying 2023 and not 2024 because there need to be eight more "A"s than "B"s at the end.
I tried Catalan-like approach, heard about "reflections" too but don't know how to apply them to this problem.

See Bertrand's Ballot Theorem

@lulu I have read it already, but I don't know how i could apply it to a case where the advantage is less than 8.

There is a simple bijection which reduces this to Bertrand's ballot theorem. Let $\pi$ be an ordering of the balls with the property that for every proper initial segment with $r$ red balls and $g$ green ball, we have $r\neq g+8$. Now, consider the reversal of $\pi$, which I denote $\pi\newcommand{\rev}{^\text{rev}}\rev$. It is easy to see that $\pi\rev$ has the property that every nonempty initial segment, $I$, with $r'$ red balls and $g'$ green balls, has $r'\neq g'$. Indeed, looking at the complement of $I$, there will be $2016-r'$ red balls and $2008-g'$ green balls. Since the complement of $I$ is an initial segment of $\pi$, from which we conclude from the property $r\neq g+8$ for $\pi$ that $(2016-r')\neq (2008-g')+8$.
Therefore, applying the $(\,\cdot\,)\rev$ bijection, we see that your problem is equivalent to finding the probability that a random ordering of $2016$ red balls and $2008$ green balls has the property that every nonempty initial segment has strictly more reds than greens. This is exactly the setup for Bertrand's ballot problem, and we deduce that the the probability of success is $(2016-2008)/(2016+2008)$.

Let me now answer your more general question.

Let $a,b$ and $k$ be positive integers. For a random ordering of $a$ votes for candidate $A$, and $b$ votes for candidate $B$, what is the probability that the running total for $A$ is never equal to $k$ plus the running total for $B$ (except possibly at the very end)?

Answer: If $a>b+k$, the probability is $[\binom{a+b}a-\binom{a+b}{a-k}]/\binom{a+b}a$. If $a=b+k$, the probability is $(a-b)/(a+b)$.
Proof: I will assume that $a\le b+k$. If $a>b+k$, then probability is $0$, since the running difference between $a$ and $b$ starts at zero and ends above $k$, so the difference must hit $k$ at some intermediate point.
If $a=b+k$, then we have the same setup as you problem ($a=2016,b=2008,k=8$). Using the same reversal bijection, this is equivalent to the usual version of Betrand's ballot theorem, and the probability is $(a-b)/(a+b)=k/(a+b)$. Therefore, from now on, we can further assume that $a<b+k$.
There are $\binom{a+b}{a}$ equally likely ways to order the ballots. We first count the number of bad orderings where some initial segment has $k$ more votes for $a$ than $b$. Given a bad ordering, $\pi$, let $\newcommand{\refl}{^\text{refl}}\pi\refl$ be the result of finding the smallest initial segment with $k$ more votes for $a$ than $b$, then complementing all votes which come after this segment.
The initial segment of $\pi$ has $k$ more $A$'s than $B$'s, which means the complementary final segment of $\pi$ has $a-b-k$ more $A$'s than $B$'s. Looking at $\pi\refl$, the initial segment still has $k$ more $A$'s than $B$'s, but the effect of complementing all votes in the final segment means that $\pi\refl$ has $k+b-a$ more $A$'s than $B$'s. Letting $a'$ and $b'$ be the total number of $A$'s and $B$'s in $\pi\refl$, we get $$\begin{align}a'-b'&=2k+b-a\\ a'+b'&=a+b\end{align}$$
The solution to this system is $a'=k+b$ and $b'=a-k$. Therefore, all of the reflected sequences consist of $k+b$ copies of $A$ and $a-k$ copies of $b$.
The key idea is that reflection is actually a bijection from the set of bad sequences to the set of all sequences of $a'=k+b$ copies of $A$ and $b'=a-k$ copies of $B$. Indeed, given a sequence with $a'$ $A$'s and $b'$ $B$'s, we have $$a'-b'=(b+k)-(a-k)=2k-(a-b)> k$$ For the last step, we use the assumption that $a-b> k$. Therefore, every path with $a'$ $A$'s and $b'$ $B$'s will have a point where the the difference between the numbers of $A$'s and $B$'s is equal to $k$; the inverse bijection is given by complementing every vote after the first such point. It follows that the number of bad paths is equal to $\binom{a+b}{a-k}$, so the number of good paths is
$$
\binom{a+b}{a}-\binom{a+b}{a-k}. 
$$
